# Unable to generate proper Data using faker for China Country

Tags: java, faker

My requirement is to create random data using faker for China country.
I am getting ??? for the data generated for CN country using faker.

For other locales like en-US and en-AU the data is generating correctly

```
Faker faker = new Faker(new Locale("zh","CN"));
faker.name().firstName() - output: ???
faker.address().streetName() - output: ???
faker.address().cityName() - output: ???
```

Can anyone help me with this issue please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Based on some limited research (a brief look at the [source code](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) on github), the `JavaFaker` library does support `Locale("zh","CN")`.

So, I think that the real problem here is the way that your JVM is handling the output.

For example, if your JVM is running with LATIN-1 (or another 8bit European character set) as the default text encoding, then it will translate Chinese characters into `?` ... which is the substitution character for codepoints that cannot be represented.

- If your console is capable of rendering Unicode (UTF-8) and you have Chinese fonts installed, try changing the console's default character encoding to UTF-8.
- If your console is already set up for UTF-8, check what System.getProperty("file.encoding") is set to.
- Read this Q&A about changing the default encoding that Java uses:

  - [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)